# How to Load PreferenceFragment in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have divided main activity in two Fragments,

the upper Portion loads the Button from xml,

& i want to load `PreferenceFragment` in thr Lower Portion ,

How to do that ??

I tried calling the Settings.class which extends PreferenceFragment directly using the following code in my Lower Portion Fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new Settings ()).commit();
```

That calls the PreferenceFragment but it Overlaps the upper Portion,

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the fragments in the activity's layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have already done that , the first fragment is fine , but on second fragment , i want to load PreferenceFragment i don't know how to do that

Comment: You just put the fragment's name for the second fragment, and that doesn't work?  What error are you getting?  If you defined them both in your layout file as I've shown, then they wouldn't overlap each other.  example: `android:name="com.example.myapp.Settings"`

Comment: I put the name , it works & loads the Preferences , but as i said , it overlaps on the First Fragment , it doesn't stays in Second Fragment