# android - How to Load PreferenceFragment in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I want a code like the following for loading `PreferenceFragment` into Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int inx = getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    View view;

    switch (inx){
        case 0:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a, container, false);
            break;
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            view = MyPreferenceFragment();
            break;
        default:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a, container, false);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off taking a step back and just loading `MyPreferenceFragment` instead of whichever fragment the above code is from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to case 2:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new {YourSettingsClass} ()).commit();
```

and declare the fragment in the activity layout.

Check this out for more info [How to Load PreferenceFragment in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432595/how-to-load-preferencefragment-in-fragment)